# Iterator-Pattern for an iterator that returns one objects that changes

Tags: java, object-oriented, design-patterns, iterator

I wrote an algorithm that returns all k-sized [subgraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_subgraph) of another given graph. Because I don't want to make the runtime of the next() call of the iterator depended on k, I don't want to return a new object every time. Instead I have one fixed instance-variable *subG* in the iterator that is changed between the calls und always represents the current subgraph that was calculated. It acts as a view that can be copied if needed if you want to use it further.
This method works fine and this is not my problem.

If I want to use *hasNext()*, I'd need to calculate the next subgraph, which would change the view *subG* as a side-effect. This is not wanted. Currently I'm using my own interface for this iterator:

```
/**
 * Interface for all iterators that always return the same object, but change it in order to return the next value.
 * Therefore, the object should not be changed unintentionally, because that would result in unwanted side-effects.
 * This prevents the use of "hasNext()" as this would have to calculate the next value for the object, but this method
 * is not expected to have side-effects. The only method that changes the object is generateNext(), which also is
 * its only purpose.
 *
 * The standard pattern for using this interface would be:
 * while (iter.hasCurrent()) {
 *     doSomethingWith(iter.getCurrent());
 *     iter.generateNext();
 * }
 */
public interface BlindIterator<T> {

    /**
     * @return True iff the current element is a valid return.
     */
    boolean hasCurrent();

    /**
     * @return Returns the current element, but does NOT generate the next element. This method can be called
     * as often as wanted, without any side-effects.
     */
    T getCurrent();

    /**Generates the next element, which can then be retrieved with getCurrent(). This method thus only provides
     * this side-effect. If it is called while the current element is invalid, it may produce and exception,
     * depending on the implementation on the iterator.
     */
    void generateNext();
}
```

I've never written something like this. Is there a better pattern for this, if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most people would be surprised and annoyed by an iterator that mutated previously yielded values every time you called `next`. While it makes sense to take what you can from the *concept* of an iterator, the thing you're trying to make isn't an iterator. (Perhaps the idea of a "cursor" would be more applicable, IDK.)

Your proposed interface `{hasCurrent, getCurrent, generateNext}` seems fine. I do have some questions/suggestions.

1. If *not* `x.hasCurrent()`, does `x.getCurrent()` return null, or throw an exception, or what?
2. Depending on 1 (particularly if it *doesn't* throw an exception), `.getCurrent()` sounds more like a read-only property, in which case just call it `.current()`. (or *maybe* even just `.value`)
3. `.generateNext()` specifically doesn't *make* anything (because we're supposing that would be expensive); it changes the thing in question. Therefore maybe call it `.mutate()` or `.becomeNext()`
4. A `void` return is usually a wasted opportunity, even if just for a little extra debugging context. Exactly what will be best to return here depends on exactly how this is going to be used. Returning boolean success might save you a call to `.hasNext()`; returning `T` might save you a call to `.current()`. Probably boolean is better, but it's hard to say.

Comment: 1. It should trow an exception if hasCurrent() is false, but I'm not sure how do implement this. Can I use default-methods for this? 2.&3. Yea, I renamed them, thanks. 4. I'll look what I need, but I also already thought about that.

Comment: But the concern about runtime is justified. This thing can generate 1 million subgraphs in a few seconds this way. Creating millions of objects takes a long time doesn't it?

Comment: I have very little experience specific to java. _How_ to throw an exception I don't recall being too finicky, if that's the way you want to go.

Comment: As for the runtime efficiency; I don't know. My intuition is that, if you structure your context so that only one (or a handful) of these millions of objects are alive in memory at once (_i.e._ they're getting garbage-collected at about the same rate as they're being generated) then it should be fine. Your concern about the cost of generating each next sub-graph scaling with the sub-graph size makes sense (of course I can't confirm it 'cause I haven't seen your code), but you're paying dearly (in terms of safety and intelligibility of your code) to avoid it with this mutable-state solution.